# MongoDB TTL doesn't delete documents if under load

Tags: mongodb

**Use case**

I am using MongoDB to persist messages from a message queue system (e. g. RabbitMQ / Kafka). Each message has a timestamp and based on that timestamp I want to expire the documents 1 hour afterwards. Therefore I've got a `deleteAt` field which is indexed and has set `expireAfterSeconds: 0`. Everything works fine, except if MongoDB is under heavy load.

We are inserting roughly 5-7k messages / second into a single replica set. The TTL Thread seems to be way slower than the rate of message coming in and thus the storage is quickly growing (which we want to avoid with TTLs).

To describe the behaviour more exactly, when I sort the messages by `deleteAt` ascending (oldest date first) I can see that it sometimes does not delete any of those messages for hours. Because of this observation I believe that the TTL thread sometimes is stuck or not active at all.

**My question**

What could I do to ensure that the TTL thread is not negatively impacted by the rate of messages coming in? According to our metrics our only bottleneck seems to be CPU, even though the SSD disk I/O is pretty high too.

Do I need to tune something (e. g. give MongoDB more threads for document deletion) so that the TTL thread can keep up with the write rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I am facing a known bug as described in MongoDB's Jira Dashboard: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19334

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/:

> The background task that removes expired documents runs every 60 seconds. As a result, documents may remain in a collection during the period between the expiration of the document and the running of the background task.
>
> Because the duration of the removal operation depends on the workload of your mongod instance, expired data may exist for some time beyond the 60 second period between runs of the background task.

I'm not aware of any way to tune that TTL thread, and I suspect you'll need to run your own cron to do batched deletes.

The other thing to look at might be what's taking up CPU and IO and see if there's any way of reducing that load.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the index with "sparse", this should perform the clean up on a separate thread in the background.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: jeff, I think you're talking about index-creation, right? I don't think that's the problem that kentor is seeing.